# Split a String with "||" seperator

Tags: jquery

I am developing an application in asp.net using c#. In my application i am using jquery for some client side operation. I have string like `BC||2||FO||NA`. I want to split this string with `||` seperator. But I failed. In the alert it is showing like `BC%7C%7C2%7C%7CFO%7C%7CNA`. How can split this string with `||`. Please help.

Comment: Use the string's `split` method with parameter `'||'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "BC||2||FO||NA";
    var res = str.split("||");
    alert(res);
}
</script>
```

**output**

```
BC,2,FO,NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split(separator)`, you will get array of string with splited parts

```js
var str = 'BC||2||FO||NA',
    splitStr = str.split('||');

alert(splitStr);
console.log(splitStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var str="BC||2||FO||NA";

    splitstr= str.split("||");

    alert(splitstr)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
 var str = "BC||2||FO||NA"; 
 var res = str.split("||");
 alert(res);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/next2u/hpcfafwb/)